# Backward Comaptibility issue and uncertainity in Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I have a use case where I have a JSON and I want to generate schema and record out of the JSON and publish a record.
I have configured the value serializer and Schema setting is Backward compatible.

First JSON

> String json = "{\n" +
>
> ```
>      "    \"id\": 1,\n" +
>
>      "    \"name\": \"Headphones\",\n" +
>
>      "    \"price\": 1250.0,\n" +
>
>      "    \"tags\": [\"home\", \"green\"]\n" +
>
>      "}\n"
>      ;
> ```

Version 1 schema registered.

Received message in avro console consumer.

Second JSON.

> String json = "{\n" +
>
> ```
>     "    \"id\": 1,\n" +
>
>     "    \"price\": 1250.0,\n" +
>     "    \"tags\": [\"home\", \"green\"]\n" +
>     "}\n"
>     ;
> ```

Registered schema Successfully.
Sent message.

Now tried sending the JSON 1 sent successfully

Schema 3:

> String json = "{\n" +
>
> ```
>     "    \"id\": 1,\n" +
>     "    \"name\": \"Headphones\",\n" +
>
>     "    \"tags\": [\"home\", \"green\"]\n" +
>     "}\n"
>     ;
> ```

Got error for this case.
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error code: 409

> How is that schema generated from 2nd JSON was registered and the
>   third one was rejected? Although I didn't have any Default key for the
>   deleted field? Is it that the Schema Registry always accepts the 1st
>   evolution? (2nd schema over 1st)

Schema in schema registry

Version 1 schema

> {
>       "fields": [
>
> ```
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '1'",
>
>   "name": "id",
>
>   "type": "int"
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '\"Headphones\"'",
>
>   "name": "name",
>
>   "type": "string"
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '1250.0'",
>
>   "name": "price",
>
>   "type": "double"
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '[\"home\",\"green\"]'",
>
>   "name": "tags",
>
>   "type": {
>
>     "items": "string",
>
>     "type": "array"
>
>   }
>
> }
> ],
> "name": "myschema",
> "type": "record"   }
> ```

Version 2:

> {
>       "fields": [
>
> ```
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '1'",
>
>   "name": "id",
>
>   "type": "int"
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '1250.0'",
>
>   "name": "price",
>
>   "type": "double"
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "doc": "Type inferred from '[\"home\",\"green\"]'",
>
>   "name": "tags",
>
>   "type": {
>
>     "items": "string",
>
>     "type": "array"
>
>   }
>
> }
> ],
> "name": "myschema",
> "type": "record"   }
> ```

Comment: Please show the schemas that were added to the registry

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the body,
Please find the schema in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go over the backwards compatibility rules... https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types

First, the default isn't transitive, so version 3 only will look at version 2.

The backwards rule states you can delete fields or add optional fields (those with a default). I assume your schema generator tool doesn't know how to use optionals, so you're only allowed to delete, not add.

Between version 1 and 2, you've deleted the name field, which is valid.

Between version 2 and the incoming 3, it thinks you're trying to post a new schema which removes price (this is okay}, but adds a required name field, which is not allowed.